# Project planning and resource management tool

Tags: project-management, resource-management

Our team is currently undergoing a significant growth, so we need to implement some resource planning. Time management is an especially critical issue (who does what? when are key persons available?).

It would be great if someone could recommend a good software for that. Ideally it should be something lightweight, since all other resources (files, collaboration etc.) are already present.

Comment: For which operating system? and what's your budget? Please also read [this FAQ on what is required for a question to contain enough information](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/6834)

Comment: There are tons of projectplanning and resource management management tools, so you'll need to be much more specific about what you need. Also, should it be standalone or on-line? How large is your team, what's the amount of data we're talking about? Please [edit] your question.

Answer (score 2):

There is an open source planning tool, [Project Libre](http://www.projectlibre.org/).

This is compatible with most of the features of Microsoft Project.

It is available for Windows, Mac and Linux.  It produces all the usual GANTT and PERT charts.  It should cover your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can check MS Project. It's quite heavy but it's very powerful.
You can manage resources, planning, ...

https://products.office.com/project/project-and-portfolio-management-software

Comment: I knew it exists, but our company seems to have no license and buying a license is quite difficult (would save boatloads of money but that is of no concern...). Is there some benefit for using ms project when we already use sharepoint / tfs / lync?